# Load data local infile stop working and it doen't give any error

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have a PHP script where I upload a CSV file and this one update/insert rows into mysql database, all is on ubuntu 18.04 server and this PHP script had many years working without problems, the server has more than 1 year working, suddenly a couple of weeks ago, with any change on server or software stop working.

The weird thing is it is not generating any error, no logs error, nothing, so i can't debug.

I read a lot this few days ago without any lucky, so i am not sure what to do.

**On my tests and testing similar problems, i found this:**

- If i run the "Load data local infile" directly on the server it works
- The file is uploading fine, i can give 777 permision and nothing changes
- infile is enabled on mysql
- apparmor is configured
- user who connect to database has FILE on privileges

**Here is the used code:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/temp/file' INTO TABLE pagos_nuevos CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(cuenta, @pago, @fpago) SET pago = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@pago,',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)), fpago = STR_TO_DATE(@fpago, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

As I said at the begining, this is no new server, this is no new code, has many years working, when debug I only received this on screen:

```
Query: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/temp/file' INTO TABLE pagos_nuevos CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(cuenta, @pago, @fpago) SET pago = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@pago,',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)), fpago = STR_TO_DATE(@fpago, '%d/%m/%Y') failed
0:
```

Where is "0:" it must to be the error code and after ":" the description of the error.

**If I remove LOCAL i get this error:**

```
Query: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/temp/file' INTO TABLE pagos_nuevos CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
(cuenta, @pago, @fpago) SET pago = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@pago,',',''),'$','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)), fpago = STR_TO_DATE(@fpago, '%d/%m/%Y')
not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

**29: File '/var/www/html/testing/unicomer/pagos/datos/pagos/pagos al 29.csv' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)**

I did a test with a user with ALL THE PRIVILEGES and do not work, so I don't know if this is a mysql issue or server issue.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if i connect to database with heidisql i can do all the process manually and works.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of error in the  file you are loading

Comment: Nope, as i mentioned on the description of the problem, if i do all the process manually all works fine....